# Вывести на экран таблицу значений функции в диапазоне от до с шагом. Значения и вводятся с клавиатуры

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    setlocale ( LC_ALL, "Russian");
    float a, b, h, y, x;
    printf("Введите a ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Введите b ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Введите h ");
    scanf("%f", &h);
    x = 0;
    while(a <= b){
        x += h;
        a += h;
        y = ((3.8 * powf(x, 3) - 1) / ((1.16 * powf(x, 2)) + 2));
        printf("y = %.2f\n", y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При некоторых случаях (Например при вводе: a = 1, b = 10, h = 3) выводится несколько чисел (Например при выводе, выводится y = 8,17; y = 18,73; y = 28,86; y = 38,84) "y". Не могу придумать как вывести последнее число выводимое принтом.

Comment: `Не могу придумать как вывести последнее число выводимое принтом.` Что это значит? Рискну предположить, что в зависимости от входных данных значение функции в точке `b` иногда выводится, а иногда нет? Или в чём вопрос?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при выводе выводилось только последнее число y, например я ввожу: a = 1, b = 10, h = 3 (a и b - это диапазон чисел, h - это шаг), исходя из этого программа выведет 4 числа, вот из этих 4-х чисел мне нужно вывести последнее, которое и будет являться ответом.

Comment: Если нужно значение функции только в одной точке, то сразу и считайте в этой точке. Цикл не нужен. `x = b-a+h; y = ...; printf("y = %.2f\n", y);`

Comment: Вообще лучше воспользоваться советом @wololo. Но если просто исправить Ваш код, то нужно функцию `printf` поставить после закрывающей скобки цикла. Тогда выведется только последнее значение.